# complex types in axis2 - Map

Tags: java, soap, dictionary, apache-axis

I m implementing web service using axis2.
The problem i m facing is with returning a complex structure in one of the methods.
Here is what i want to do:

as a return type - `Map<String, Pair[]>` where Pair is

```
    public class Pair {

        private String key;
        private String value;
...........
}
```

i m testing it with SoapUI

and the return is always empty
here is a simple response i got

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:getSNSTrendsResponse xmlns:ns="http://soap.sso.vwdcrm.app.mailprofiler.com">
         <ns:return xsi:type="ax211:SNSData" xmlns:ax212="http://util.java/xsd" xmlns:ax211="http://objects.soap.sso.vwdcrm.app.mailprofiler.com/xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <ax211:errorCode>1</ax211:errorCode>
            <ax211:errorMessage xsi:nil="true"/>
            <ax211:pairsResponse xsi:type="axis2ns2:anyType">
               <empty xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">false</empty>
            </ax211:pairsResponse>
            <ax211:response xsi:nil="true"/>
         </ns:return>
      </ns:getSNSTrendsResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope
```

where pairResponse should contains the result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java generics (contrary to arrays types for instance) are erased during compilation, thus for Axis `Map<String, Pair[]>` is the same thing as `Map`.

The usual way of representing key-to-object mapping in Java SOAP is to use an array where objects contain their key.

In your case, if your Map is indexed by `Pair.key` value, then using a `Pair[]` should work.